# How to execute ssh-keygen without prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to automate generate a pair of ssh key using shell script on Centos7, and I have tried

```
yes "y" | ssh-keygen -t rsa
echo "\n\n\n" | ssh-keygen...
echo | ssh-keygen..
```

all of these command doesn't work, just input one 'enter' and the shell script stopped on "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase)",
I just want to know how to simulate mutiple 'enter' in shell continuously.

Many thanks if anyone can help !

Answer (score 224, accepted):

We need to accomplish **two steps** automatically:

1. **Enter a passphrase**. Use the `-N` flag (void string for this example):

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ''`
2. **Overwrite the key file**:

Use `-f` to enter the path (in this example `id_rsa`) plus a **here-string** to answer *yes* to the following question:

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa <<<y >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or, under a `bash` like shell, If you **certainly want to overwrite the previous one**,  use just a **here-string** to *feed the command* with all the need *input*:

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' <<< $'\ny' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

From `ssh-keygen` *man* page:

> ```
>   -N new_passphrase provides the new passphrase.
>   -q                silence ssh-keygen.
>   -f filename       specifies the filename of the key file.
> ```

---

**Step by step explanation**

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/klashxx/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

**1**) To avoid entering the key use `-f`:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
/home/klashxx/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)?
```

**ATTENTION**: If you don't care about the RSA file name and certainly want to overwrite the previous one, check the instructions below point four.

**2**) Now we need to answer "**y**" automatically to the *overwrite question* (let's use a [*here-string*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) for that job):

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa <<< y
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
/home/klashxx/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

**3**) Finally we're going to use the `-N` flag to enter a void pass:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa <<< y
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
/home/klashxx/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? Your identification has been saved in /home/klashxx/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/klashxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:Xo0t6caMB/8TSsigxfY28JIfqYjyqxRZrFrPncx5yiU klashxx@server
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|  .              |
|   o .           |
|  +   *    =     |
| +.  + BSo= o    |
|...o.+o+XO...    |
|.. .o.E==+B. .   |
|o . ...=.o...    |
|.+o.  o     ..   |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

**4**) *Extra ball*, cleanup the output, just check the return code:

```
$ ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa <<<y >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?
0
```

---

**An alternative path to overwrite the previous RSA file (no -f flag needed)**

**NOTE**: Only `bash` like shells.

If you don't care about the RSA name and just want to overwrite it, we need to answer these two questions automatically:

> 1. Enter file in which to save the key: /example/path/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
> 2. Overwrite (y/n)?

If we do this by hand, for the first question we just need to hit *enter*, and for the second, type `y` and press `enter`.

We can simulate these actions by using the following [*here-string*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings):

`$'\ny'`

From the `bash` man page:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
> "string", with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by
> the ANSI C standard.
>
> \n     new line

So, if we use `od` to analyze our string:

```
cat - <<< $'\ny' | od -c
0000000  \n   y  \n
```

We see that we're getting just what we need to answer the questions.

**Points 1 and 2 can be summarized into**:

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa  <<< $'\ny'
```

And the **final command** will be:

```
$ ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' <<< $'\ny' >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?
0
```

---

**Kudos**

@lukasz-dynowski, @redochka, @mellow-yellow, @yeti and the rest of the folks in this thread.

Comment: I have known this way, but I just want to use 'ssh-keygen -t rsa' to implement.

Comment: Then without the `-N` flag have any solutions?

Comment: You can use `expect` but seems to complicated when `-N` handle it nicely.

Comment: Just want to add in here that if you want to overwrite id_rsa, you need to append the -f flag to this answer. For me, this was creating a y and y.pub rsa key file pair. This code fixed it: 

`yes y | ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -n ''  -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa >/dev/null`

Comment: @ingage: `yes y | ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa >/dev/null` Otherwise it asks passphrase

Comment: Second method doesn't work on Windows. Any alternative solutions?

Comment: Maybe something like `echo y|ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' > NUL`

Comment: You can also do: `IDRSA=~/.ssh/id_rsa; rm -f $IDRSA && ssh-keygen -t rsa -q -N "" -f $IDRSA`

Comment: Great answer though the right order of redirection is: `>/dev/null 2>&1`

`2>&1 >/dev/null` results in stdout to /dev/null and stederr to stdout which is not what is intended

Comment: These commands fail for me in Docker with `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: This answer ended up being useful to me, yet interesting the OP never asked about overwriting the key file?

Comment: For anyone using Powershell to do it - `-N` parameter does not accept `''` as empty string, there is `[string]::Empty`

Answer (score 50):

If you don't want to prompt user for a file in which to save the key, you can add file output flag `-f` to the command.

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This way, user will not be prompted for any input -unless **id_rsa** file(s) already exist.

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers do exactly what is expected. The wanted behavior: run ssh-keygen with default settings (like if we just spammed Enter) without ever prompting for input.

The command to run is:

```
yes '' | ssh-keygen -N '' > /dev/null
```

leave out the >/dev/null if you want to print output.

Explanation:
`yes y` spams 'y', which ssh-keygen takes literally and makes the keys in $PWD/y and $PWD/y.pub . `yes ''` spams empty lines (Enter) which is what we want. Specifying the file with -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa fails if .ssh directory doesn't exist. The -t rsa option is not required if rsa is the default type (we're spamming enter anyways). The passphrase is not read from stdin (which we're spamming enters on) but from the keyboard directly so nothing can intercept it. For this reason you need to specify -N '' for empty passphrase.

Comment: I have `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3` and `yes '' | ssh-keygen -N '' > /dev/null` won't work here. In my version, `ssh-keygen` need an explicit acceptance so `yes 'yes' | ... `.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the current private key to prevent overwriting requests.

```
rm -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa && ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I noticed that the question did not ask to delete the current key.

Comment: sometimes the most obvious answer is the most underrated.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer still specifies a custom filename. This worked for me:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' <<<$'\n'
```

- `-t rsa` Specifies type of key to create (RSA).
- `-b 4096` Specifies the number of bits in the key to create (4096 bits).
- `-N ''` Provides the passphrase (empty, in this case).
- `<<<` Part of shell: "here string" to feed a string into the stdin of ssh-keygen.
- `$'\n'` A newline (using $ to make the single-quoted string interpret special characters).

The command as given above creates a 4096-bit RSA key with an empty passphrase. It asks: `Enter file in which to save the key (.../.ssh/id_rsa):`, hence a newline (`\n`) is fed into the stdin, to automatically accept the default filename. If a key already exists, it will not do anything.

However, if you do wish to **automatically overwrite** an existing key without any prompt, then use (*this is the real answer to the original question, but it's down here to prevent unintended overwriting for people who copy&paste without reading*):

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' <<<$'\ny\n'
```

To **silence** ssh-keygen stdout, either add the `-q` (quiet) option or `>/dev/null`:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' <<<$'\n' >/dev/null
```

Comment: perfect! This works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

For me, i had to use combination of both @Lukasz answer and @Juan one, when using in ssh command

```
ssh -p$SSH_PORT -q joker@$INSTANCE_IP 'yes y | ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside my Dockerfile (From node:8.13.0), the following works nicely: `yes 'y' | /usr/bin/ssh-keygen`

More complete example:

```sh
yes 'y' | /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -q -N '' -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key && \
yes 'y' | /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -q -N '' -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Answer (score 0):

From the accepted answer above, I created my own version

> ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa <</dev/null 2>&1 && cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy

It will automatically create the ssh key and copy the public key to the clipboard --> which allows me to paste to github, azure dev...