# Double quote and dollar prefix string in shell

Tags: bash, shell, herestring

In the question [How to execute ssh-keygen without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235179/how-to-execute-ssh-keygen-without-prompt?answertab=active#tab-top) I find they use the here string like this:

```
""$'\n'"y"
```

Why do they need double quote before `$`? It seems `$'\n'y` is equal to it:

```sh
bash$ cat - <<< ""$'\n'"y" | od -c
0000000 \n y \n
0000003
bash$ cat - <<< $'\n'y | od -c
0000000 \n y \n
0000003
```

Comment: I've edited the linked answer to remove the wholly unnecessary `""`.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I'm not sure if they have any special meaning in double quotes

Comment: They have none. Quotes just perform bulk escaping: `"foo"` is the same as `\f\o\o`. If there's nothing in the quotes to escape, they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason; the empty double-quoted string is completely unnecessary.

The shell uses quoting to group tokens which would otherwise be split. `token` is precisely equivalent to `""token` or `"token"` (or `""""""""""token` or `"""t"o"k"e"n"` etc if you will) after quote removal.

The only place you really need an empty string is when an argument should be a string of length zero (like `printf '%s\n' "first line" "" "third line"` where the penultimate argument is an empty string) though it can also occasionally be useful for disambiguation (`"$HOMEdir"` is distinct from `"$HOME""dir"` where the former attempts to expand a variable whose name is seven characters long; though usually you'd use `"${HOME}dir"` to make this distinction).

---

(Multiple adjacent quotes have no significance to the shell; `""""` is simply the empty string `""` next to the empty string `""`.)

Comment: Some users erroneously try to use quotes for disambiguation where they do not disambiguate at all. `echo "-e"` is precisely equivalent to `echo -e` and does not allow you to output the literal string `-e` (finally learn to use `printf '%s\n' -e` instead if you need that).